# Sanitise user inputs for injection into Curl CURLOPT_USERPWD values

Tags: php, curl, sanitization

This might sound a little obscure, but in a nutshell I'm building a sort of middleman wrapper API endpoint which uses HTTP basic auth but validates the user submitted auth credentials by re-using them in another HTTP basic auth connection to another endpoint.

I.e, I'm using Curl to connect to another endpoint and within that, I'm using the user-provided auth credentials as auth credentials for that request. So I'm doing this:

```
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] . ":" . $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']);
```

But obviously this needs sanitising. Apart from anything else, presumably if the user passes a username or password containing a colon, this is going to be a problem since colons are used to separate the two values. I'm sure there will be other characters not allowed in basic auth usernames too, or allowed but that need escaping?

Should I literally just rawurlencode() for these? I believe Curl is effectively passing these headers as url params so that's what makes sense to me, but I can't find anything concrete?

Obviously familiar with escaping and sanitising inputs in general, I'm just not used to hacking user inputs into Curl headers!

Comment: [RFC2617](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2617.txt) explicitly forbids colons in userids for basic auth: `userid = *<TEXT excluding ":">` If you're already using basic auth to get `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']` then it should be impossible to get a value with a colon in it. That said, it certainly wouldn't hurt to check for one, and abort if found.

Comment: (Note it's ok for the password to have a colon because the string is split at the first one encountered.)

Comment: Thanks Alex. So, you'd just do this then? `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, str_replace(':', '', $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) . ":" . $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']);` without any actual escaping?

Comment: No. In theory, your existing code is fine and you don't have to do anything further, because there should never be a colon in the userid to begin with. In practice, you may want to double check. `if (strpos($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'], ':') !== false) throw new Exception('Illegal username');`